# Angular Routing and Node Redirect

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, redirect, saml

I am trying to add SAML authentication using passport-saml for my application. I am using Angular for routing. On loading of the homepage, I check for a user through a GET request to my node server "/auth" to check `req.user`, if it's true, I send back logged in user data; if false, I send back an error message. I have data binding on this user data response so in the event of no user data, I still show "Log in" button.

On click of the "Log in" button, I perform a redirect to the node server "/login". This does passport.authenticate function which runs and then ties in with "/assert" when it's complete to perform a redirect.** It is at this point I am running into a problem.** My redirect always goes to "/" because I am performing a redirect and using angular routing so I dont know how to store this route say "/myPage1" or "/myPage2". NOTE: I do not want to always send back to "/myPage1", I want to be able to "Login" from any view in the SPA.

Am I going about this in the wrong way? Is this a limitation of using Angular routing?

#### Angular

```
    $scope.login = function () {
        window.location.href = 'http://example.com/login';
    };

    function getCreds() {
        $http.get('http://example.com/auth', { withCredentials: true })
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.creds = response.data;
            });
    }
```

#### Node.js

```
app.get('/login', passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/login' }));

app.post("/assert", passport.authenticate('saml', { failureRedirect: '/login' }), function (req, res) {
    // console.log('session' + JSON.stringify(req.session));
    // console.log("original url " + req.session.originalUrl);
    if (req.session.originalUrl) {
        res.redirect(req.session.originalUrl);
    }
    else {
        res.redirect('/');
    } 
});

app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {
    var authenticated = req.user;
    if (authenticated) {
        res.send(req.user);
    } else {
        res.send({statusCode: 401, message: 'User session is not alive'});
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a way to achieve the desired effect.

Before making the "Login" call, I make another api call to "/setSessionRedirectUrl" which passes the current window.location.href from angular to node server for session storage.

```
app.post('/setSessionRedirectUrl', function (req, res) {
    req.session.samlLoginRedirectUrl = req.body.redirectUrl;
    res.send();
});
```

Then when the assert function is being run after login, it is looking for the `req.session.samlLoginRedirectUrl` to redirect to. It works!